Wrong interpolation of colormap points using surf pgfplots
I've been using \addplot[surf] to plot a 2D colormap with 1024 points. These points are aligned vertically along the XY plane, but I am facing problems to understand why the map is distorted. I’ve noticed that mesh/cols and mesh/rows values drastically change the output map. How should I define them correctly? Should I use \matrixcols and \matrixrows instead of mesh/cols and mesh/rows?
I’m not sure if this is the reason why my temperature map is connecting the points at the boundaries wrongly. I created an example with only 25 points, and the map came out perfect, but I tested a uniform temperature variation, like here:

to PGFplot addplot3(+) discrete data -> smooth surface

When the temperature variation is not uniform, the provided map got disturbed.
Here is the MWE with the data.txt I'm trying to plot:
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.18,
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$X$},
            ylabel={$Y$},
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            set thousands separator = {\.},
            set decimal separator = {,},
            ytick distance=0.5,
            xmin = 0.,
            ymin = -2.5,
            xmax = 20., %\xmaxvalue,
            ymax = 2.5, %\ymaxvalue,
            colorbar,
            colorbar style={title={(°F)}},
            colormap/hot,
            title={Temperature},
            ]
            \addplot[
                surf,
                shader= interp,
                %patch type=bilinear,
                %matrix plot*,
                point meta=explicit,
                mesh/cols=32, %\matrixcols,
                mesh/rows=32, % \matrixrows,
                mesh/check = false,
                ] table [
                x expr=\thisrow{x}, y expr=\thisrow{y},
                meta=c
                ]{data.txt};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


EDIT: As I had suspected, the number of rows and columns were wrong (I had misinterpreted these parameters). RESOLVED!

Welcome to TeX.SX!  Try to reproduce your issue with a smaller data.txt file and include it in your minimal working example (MWE) between \begin{filecontent} and \end{filecontent}, so anybody can copy/paste your code and test it.

Step one is not to use mesh/check = false,. -and then only give either mesh/rows or mesh/cols. You probably do not have 3232 points, but something line 3133 and one extra. The problem is your data and not LaTeX/PGFPlots. -it is therefore impossible to help.

Thank you @hpekristiansen ! The right input is 31*33. I had missundestand how to define mesh/rows and mesh/cols.
